# What is wrong with my requirejs setup?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My requirejs config file looks correct to me.  But when I get into my function to fire up my application, I only have access to jQuery.  Could someone look at my config file and tell me what I am doing wrong?  Why can't I see Backbone or Underscore and why can I see jQuery?  Here is my config file:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: "libs/jquery/jquery",
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
    backbone: "libs/backbone/backbone"
  },
  shims: {
    backbone: {
      deps: [
        'underscore',
        'jquery'
      ],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    }
  }
});

require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {
  'use strict';

  debugger;
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have shims instead of shim in singular, changing it should fix your issue.

```
shim: {
   underscore: {
     exports: '_'
   },
   backbone: {
     deps: [
      'underscore',
      'jquery'
     ],
     exports: 'Backbone'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The versions of underscore and backbone you are using are not AMD compliant, so they don't return in the way require.js needs them to. You can just leave them off of your function params and they will be available on the global scope. Otherwise, you are passing undefined into your function as the value of _ and Backbone.

```
require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function() {
  console.log($);
  console.log(_);
  console.log(Backbone);
});
```

Comment: thats the reason he is using shim in require, because he is not using the AMD compliant versions.

Comment: yes it is, but there is no reason to use shim, because they will be global anyway

Comment: No, as he is declaring them using require not a regular script tag in the html, so at the time to require backbone without shim it will  fail.

Comment: I thought one of the purposes of require was to not have a bunch of globals?  So each one of those 3 is now a global?

Comment: yes, but that is unavoidable unless OP is using AMD compliant versions of his files (underscore, backbone)

Comment: please take a look at the response of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765336/require-js-shim-config-global-scope

Comment: yes, it says exactly what i said: "Backbone and Underscore both modify the global scope, so if the browser has run their code, then the globals will exist."

Comment: :) you missed this part ...This will happen if loading as a shim in RequireJS, or as if you included a script tag with their src directly.

Comment: what is your point? yes, that is true, that's why i said the shim is irrelevant, both our solutions work, but mine is less lines of code